# execution of JAVA application with System.load(dll)

Tags: java, linux

is it possible to run java app on linux (with installed java and etc) server with this execution of a command inside the java application?

```
System.load("path to .dll");
```

And.. 
www.mono-project.com can help me do my task for this application?

Comment: Don't think so. this path is not available under linux

Comment: How are you expecting this command to execute? There's not even a "C" drive on Linux. Not to mention loading DLLs.

(It might work in Wine or something similar).

Comment: sorry i was using copy/paste for code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DLLs are Windows-specific native libraries. You cannot normally use a Windows DLL on a non-Windows operating system such as Linux. You'll need to have a Linux version of the DLL; this normally has the extension `.so`.

The Mono project is an open-source implementation of Microsoft's .NET framework that runs on Linux (and other non-Microsoft operating systems). It does not help you to run arbitrary DLLs on non-Windows operating systems.

Comment: this is the answer I'm looking for "does not help you to run arbitrary DLLs on non-Windows operating systems."  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work on Mono but you might want to look at:

[Launching an application (.EXE) from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240171/launching-a-application-exe-from-c)

And here is a Mono example:

[mono Process.Start how to find bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699109/mono-process-start-how-to-find-bash)

I'm wondering did you even do a search? :)